# Python C API: why doesn't PyRun_String evaluate simple conditional expressions?

Tags: python, python-c-api

```
PyRun_String("if True: 1\nelse: 0", Py_eval_input, globals, globals);
```

returns error with PyErr_Print() printing out:

```
File "<string>", line 1
  if True: 1
   ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a conditional expression: it's a statement. `Py_eval_input` means to treat the string as a single expression. You probably want `Py_single_input` to treat the string as a statement.

This is the same as the distinction in Python code between `eval` (which is what you asked for) and `exec`.

I am assuming of course that the statement you actually want to execute will be slightly more complex otherwise there isn't much point using either `eval` or `exec`. For `exec` you'll want to make sure it has side effects so you can tell the result, e.g. by binding some value to a name.

Comment: I'm new to python. I tried "1 if True else 0" and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I thought of suggesting that but wrongly assumed that you wouldn't be playing with the C-api until you had some experience with Python itself. BTW, if you are doing more than just running a simple expression or statement consider using Cython instead of using the C-api directly.

Answer (score 0):

It does, but you're not doing anything that will produce output or return a value.

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def foo():
    if True: 1
    else: 0

a = foo()

print(a)
```

a will not get the value 0 or 1 - it will be 'None'.

Comment: This would be the problem if there was no output, but not the source of this particular exception.